# Guzzle/Nexmo Issues After Upgrading to Laravel 8

Tags: php, laravel, vonage, envoyer.io, laravel-envoyer

I recently performed a rather large update to this web app, and for the most part it went off without a hitch... Until the app tries to send an SMS notification from staging/production.

The upgrade from laravel 7.x to 8.x was quite simple and straightforward. At the same time we also installed Laravel Horizon. Everything went according to plan, and all works fine locally.

When we deploy to staging/production however, queued SMS notifications fail with the following exception:

> ReflectionException: Class Http\Adapter\Guzzle6\Client does not exist in /home/forge/dev.example.com/releases/20210609194554/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php:836

Looking in the stack trace we can see that Nexmo is the culprit:

> #5 /home/forge/dev.example.com/releases/20210609194554/vendor/nexmo/laravel/src/NexmoServiceProvider.php(150): Illuminate\Foundation\Application->make()

However in our composer.json file we are requiring Guzzle 7 with the following:

`"guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^7.3",`

It is worth mentioning again at this point, I have no issues sending SMS locally, the main difference between local and staging environments is that locally I use Laravel Valet and Staging uses Laravel Envoyer.

What I've tried so far:

- Changing `"guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^7.3"` to `"guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^6.5|^7.3"`
- Running `php artisan horizon:purge` and `php artisan horizon:terminate` both manually and in a deployment hook.
- Restarting the laravel horizon daemon on forge.
- trying `php artisan queue:restart`
- running `composer dump-autoload` and `composer dump-autoload -o`
- deleting composer.lock and the vendor/ directory from current/ then running `composer install`
- Restarting PHP, Nginx, and eventually the entire server :(

and more...

Any help is greatly appreciated

UPDATE Below:

Complete composer.json:

```
{
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
    "license": "MIT",
    "type": "project",
    "require": {
        "php": ">=7.4.1",
        "arrilot/laravel-widgets": "^3.13",
        "barryvdh/laravel-snappy": "^0.4.6",
        "doctrine/dbal": "^2.10",
        "facade/ignition": "^2.3.6",
        "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^7.3",
        "intervention/image": "^2.4",
        "laravel/framework": "^8.0",
        "laravel/helpers": "^1.3",
        "laravel/horizon": "^5.7",
        "laravel/nexmo-notification-channel": "^2.5.1",
        "laravel/passport": "^10.0",
        "laravel/slack-notification-channel": "^2.0",
        "laravel/telescope": "^4.0",
        "laravel/tinker": "^2.0",
        "laravel/ui": "^3.0",
        "league/csv": "^8.2",
        "league/flysystem-aws-s3-v3": "~1.0",
        "maatwebsite/excel": "^3.1",
        "milon/barcode": "^8.0.1",
        "nexmo/laravel": "^2.4.1",
        "nunomaduro/collision": "^5.0",
        "predis/predis": "^1.1",
        "pusher/pusher-php-server": "^4.1.1",
        "webpatser/laravel-uuid": "^3.0"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "fzaninotto/faker": "~1.4",
        "mockery/mockery": "0.9.*",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "^9.0",
        "filp/whoops": "~2.0"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "classmap": [
            "database"
        ],
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Tests\\": "tests/"
        }
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-root-package-install": [
            "php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "php artisan key:generate"
        ],
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postInstall"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postUpdate"
        ],
        "post-autoload-dump": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump",
            "@php artisan package:discover"
        ]
    },
    "config": {
        "preferred-install": "dist",
        "sort-packages": true
    }
}
```

Additionally my nexmo config file does not have anything for http_client, maybe it's an upgrade step I missed somewhere along the line. As such, I have nothing in my .env file for nexmo's http_client. I will begin looking into this as well.

nexmo.php

```
<?php

return [

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | API Credentials
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | If you're using API credentials, change these settings. Get your
    | credentials from https://dashboard.nexmo.com | 'Settings'.
    |
    */

    'api_key'    => function_exists('env') ? env('NEXMO_KEY', '') : '',
    'api_secret' => function_exists('env') ? env('NEXMO_SECRET', '') : '',

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Signature Secret
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | If you're using a signature secret, use this section. This can be used
    | without an `api_secret` for some APIs, as well as with an `api_secret`
    | for all APIs.
    |
    */

    'signature_secret' => function_exists('env') ? env('NEXMO_SIGNATURE_SECRET', '') : '',

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Private Key
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Private keys are used to generate JWTs for authentication. Generation is
    | handled by the library. JWTs are required for newer APIs, such as voice
    | and media
    |
    */

    'private_key' => function_exists('env') ? env('NEXMO_PRIVATE_KEY', '') : '',
    'application_id' => function_exists('env') ? env('NEXMO_APPLICATION_ID', '') : '',

    /*
    |----------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Phone Numbers
    |----------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Phone numbers to be used by the application.
    */

    'number'    =>  env('NEXMO_NUMBER'),
    'batch'     =>  env('NEXMO_BATCH'),

];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see that the [`NexmoServiceProvider`](https://github.com/Nexmo/nexmo-laravel/blob/029bdc19fc58cd6ef0aa75c7041d82b9d9dc61bd/src/NexmoServiceProvider.php#L150) is trying to use the defined `http_client` in the config, so can you share what the `.env` has for `NEXMO_HTTP_CLIENT` ? I am pretty sure you have something wrong there or even not defined.

And this is what it is defined in the `config/nexmo.php` related to that config:

```php
'http_client' => function_exists('env') ? env('NEXMO_HTTP_CLIENT', '') : '',
```

Comment: Good call, I am missing http_client from the nexmo config entirely. I must have missed something pertaining to this in one of the upgrades along the way. I have updated my question with the composer.json and config/nexmo.php files. I am going to begin researching the http_client config setting.

Comment: @JustinM151 no worries at all, this things sometimes happens. Looking at the code (`NexmoServiceProvider`) I have shared, I am pretty sure you have to write `NEXMO_HTTP_CLIENT="\GuzzleHttp\Client"` and that should do it. It requires a class so the Laravel Service Container can make it and it requires to be implementing `ClientInterface`, so that object I shared is implementing it. Test that and tell me if it worked

Comment: [This](https://github.com/Nexmo/nexmo-laravel/blob/029bdc19fc58cd6ef0aa75c7041d82b9d9dc61bd/src/NexmoServiceProvider.php#L153) (see [here](https://github.com/Vonage/vonage-php-sdk-core/blob/2b734ff7d86d4b6f169df49aed3aefcdac7a40d0/src/Client.php#L149)) needs a `ClientInterface` and [`GuzzleHttp\Client`](https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle/blob/de6f1e58e735754b888649495ed4cb9ae3b19589/src/Client.php#L17) implements it.

Comment: I got it sorted with your nudge in the right direction. Thank you very much!

Comment: Glad I was of help ! I was going to share that it was trying to use `Guzzle6` [here](https://github.com/Vonage/vonage-php-sdk-core/blob/2b734ff7d86d4b6f169df49aed3aefcdac7a40d0/src/Client.php#L151-L167), that was the error, but good to know you sorted it out now !

Comment: @JustinM151 how did you solve it? I tried adding "\GuzzleHttp\Client" but it did not work.